# sample/example to setup data entry form

Tags: jquery, forms, data-entry

I see many examples with jquery, bootstrap, jqueryvalidation. However, they are usually small logins and such with one column of data.

Suppose one has a internal web app that needs many fields entered for data forms.  samples or examples for layout of large data entry forms with many fields which will be used *only* on desktop? (Still may have multiple supported browsers though.)

Comment: You won't get an opinion on this forums, you will have to have a specific question about programming to get a good response around here. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what dev. environment you want to work in.  It also depends on what backend database you are using:

**If phpmyadmin**: Check out this 4 video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2-neLr7MXM

**If asp.net**:  Check out this 11 video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPGrK52ccDM&list=PLtMFeKNXw-GH0wC0tTM1Tb8wgOw7NV9EJ

**Ruby on the Rails**: Search Youtube (stack won't let me post more than two links or I'd give you a link):

I'm assuming you're not using wordpress, but if you're just looking for an input form than that's very doable on a Wordpress plugin (stack won't let me post more than two links or I'd give you a link).